# Convert a POSCAR-format-like file to a XSF file?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, computational-chemistry

How do I convert  a POSCAR-format-like file to a XSF file (visualized by [XCrySDen](http://www.xcrysden.org/))?

I'm looking for a step by step tutorial on the process and what tools/programs are needed.

Comment: [Vesta](https://jp-minerals.org/vesta/en/) can handle both POSCAR and XSF. Try opening the file in Vesta and exporting it. If that doesn't work, try searching for [previous questions](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/4773/read-a-data-file-into-the-atoms-object-in-ase) such as this, where the [ASE](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/index.html) package is used.

Comment: Just type `atomsk POSCAR xsf`   check documetation of atomsk https://atomsk.univ-lille.fr/doc/en/formats.html

Comment: @pranavkumar seems you can write an answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are couple of tools which can quickly convert POSCAR to xsf format.

### Atomsk

The basic syntax to convert POSCAR to xsf:
`atomsk POSCAR xsf`

### VASPKIT

Inside the structure editor there is the option

```
406) Convert POSCAR/CONTCAR to Other Formats
```

The xsf format is one of the available options.

### ASE

```py
from ase.io import vasp
from ase.io import xsf
a=vasp.read_vasp('POSCAR')
xsf.write_xsf('new.xsf',a)
```

The above Python script should convert a POSCAR file to `new.xsf`
You can also look at another [python script](https://github.com/QijingZheng/VaspVib2XSF) which can convert other types of VASP files.

### Custom Bash script

This [GitHub repo](https://github.com/houzf/poscar2xsf) made by user houzf has a bash script to do this conversion.